# "extensions folder" empty: python essentials for spss 18

Tags: python, installation, spss

I've downloaded the `PASWStatistics_PythonEssentials_1802_win64.exe` extension bundle for `PASW Statistics 18` (located [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/files/app?lang=en#/collection/17bf4269-b67a-413e-ac87-9870eabeaf53)). For some reason, in PASW Statistics 18, when I go to `"Utilities>Extension Bundle>View Installed Extension Bundle"` it shows that nothing is installed. When I go to `"Utilities>Extension Bundle>Install Extension Bundle"` and navigate to `C:\Program Files\SPSSInc\PASWStatistics18\extensions`, that folder is empty.

Prior to installing `PASWStatistics_PythonEssentials_1802_win64.exe`, I installed Python version 2.6. I am running windows 7 64 bit. PASW Statistics 18 and Python version 2.6 is 64 bit.

Any ideas as to what could be happening? Any help is much appreciated.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

When you install the Essentials, it automatically installs Python at the same time.

First thing to check: are you actually running 64-bit Statistics?  Statistics could be either 32 or 64 bit on 64-bit Win7.

Run this from a syntax window.
Begin program.
Import SPSS
Print SPSS
End program.

-- all the above should be in lower case.  My iPad is fighting me.

Also, you should install the Essentials using Run as Administrator or the installer might not be able to write the files.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I double checked and PASW 18 Statistics is 64 bit. What will running that syntax achieve? When I run it I get: "ImportError: No module named SPSS." I uninstalled Essentials and re-installed it as an administrator. The "extensions" folder is still empty. I read a post by a mac user and for some reason they said that essentials was installed in some seemingly random SPSS folder. They had to transfer essentials to their empty "extensions" folder. Could that be whats happening here? Also, do i need the python plugin to be installed (I read that it wasn't required)?

Comment: Essentials only works with version 18.0.2 and up and I have 18.0.0, so I assume that's why its not working. I've searched the IBM website and can't seem to locate where to download the upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

The Essentials do work with V18, although some particular extension commands might have a higher requirement, but there are some tricky installation configurations that might have been better dealt with in a later release.

For that "no module named SPSS" message.  If you actually did import SPSS, please try again with lower case.  However, getting that message means that the basic Python configuration was working, or else it wouldn't have been able to complain.

Run SHOW EXT from the syntax window to see what locations are on the extension search path and see if any of those locations have what you expected.  (I'm not positive that SHOW EXT was available in 18, but give it a try.)

Answer (score 0):

> Essentials only works with version 18.0.2 and up and I have 18.0.0, so I 
>   assume that's why its not working. I've searched the IBM website and can't >seem to locate where to download the upgrade. – user3242245 Dec 8 '14 at 18:51

yes you're right:essentialts do not work with V18.0.0. I've found that the 18.0.0 version should be updated to 18.0.1 and than to 18.0.2.  But I can't find the proper patch for that! As I understood that was so long time ago so the IBM dismissed those old patches from the open source...